# Converting from parent template class to child template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base template class.

```
template <typename T, int width>
struct mat
```

One of the derived template classes is

```
template <typename T>
struct mat4 : public mat<T, 4>
```

but when I try to multiply two matrices and assign them

```
mat4<float> model(1.0f);
mat4<float> model2(1.0f);
mat4<float> a = model * model2;
```

I get error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'maths::mat' to 'maths::mat4'. How do I tell the compiler that `mat4<T>` and `mat<T,4>` are the equal to each other? Because so far they are being interpreted as different types which is stopping the assignment operator from working because it can not convert from a `mat<T, 4>` to `mat4<T>`?

Additional information about my implementation:

operator=

```
template<typename T, int width>
inline mat<T, width>& mat<T, width>::operator=(const mat<T, width>& rhs)
{
    *this = rhs;
}
```

operator*

```
template<typename T, int width>
inline mat<T, width> mat<T, width>::operator*(const mat<T, width>& rhs)const{
mat<T, width> ans;

for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        T elementSum = T(0);
        for (int f = 0; f < width; f++) {
            elementSum += elements[x + f * width] * rhs.elements[f + y * width];
        }
        ans.elements[x + y * width] = elementSum;
    }
}
return ans;
```

mat4 constructor

```
mat4(const T scalar = T())
    :mat<T, 4>{ scalar }
{};
```

mat constructor

```
template<typename T, int width>
inline mat<T, width>::mat(const T scalar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++)
         ((i % (width+1)) == 0) ? (elements[i] = (T)1 * scalar)
                                : (elements[i] = (T)0);
}
```

Comment: Does `mat4` actually extend `mat` functionality in any way? Maybe simple `using` statement would be better? Because to use polymorphism in C++, you need a pointer or a reference. And templates don't mix well with polymorphism (e.g. you cannot use `virtual`)

Comment: Otherwise, you need to have operators also defined in derived class. What is the purpose of the derived class?

Comment: I add functionality like rotation, translation, inverse matrices, determinants and more. How could you use a using statement?

Comment: `using` simply creates an alias for name, so you could type `mat4<float>` instead of `mat<float, 4>`, but it's still precisely the same class. If you have more functionality in child class, it won't do.

Comment: Ah ok got you so  template <typename T>
                             using mat4<T> = mat<T, 4>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a converting constructor to `mat4` that accepts `mat`:

```
template <typename T>
mat4<T>::mat4(const mat<T, 4> &that)
    : mat<T, 4>(that) { }
```

Note that `mat4<float> a = model * model2;` statement doesn't actually use the assignment operator despite it being present there syntactically. Instead the [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) occurs using one of the available non-explicit constructors.

Comment: So I had to explicitly tell mat4<T> to call the copy constructor from mat<T, 4>. Thank you a lot spent 5 hours trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the operators defined in the base `mat` are returning references to `mat` not `mat4`, even when there's an inheritance relation between them, there's nothing telling the compiler how to go from `mat4` to `mat`, remember the *is-a* relation.

What you need is a converting constructor in `mat4` as:

```
template <typename T>
struct mat4 : public mat<T, 4>
{
    template <int width, typename std::enable_if<(width == 4), bool>::type = true>
    mat4(mat<T, width> const& b) : mat<T, width>(b)
    { }
};
```